# Realtek r8168 RTL8111/8168 Rev 3 drivers installed but still no wired connection to internet on 13.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.04, realtek, wired

I've literally tried everything to try and get the internet to work
i downloaded the realtek drivers from realteks official website and i put them on a flash drive then compiled them in terminal and installed and everything appears to be 
successful i blacklisted the realtek 8169 
which was the default kernel installed for me.
i ran modprobe -r realtek
it shows r8168 is running.
then at the top of the screen
it shows i have a wired connection and its working with the up and down arrows (which wasnt there before) in network manager but when i go to use the firefox browser it says use offline.
and the network disconnects it appears like its disconnecting on and off flashing
like its trying to connect but cant make a full connection.
i tried changing the connection to DHCP,turned off ipv6 their must be something im unaware of that im not doing.
this has been extremely frustrating any additional information ill be glad to provide thank you.

heres some logs out of terminal

`lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5/GA-EG45M-DS2H Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: ea000000-edffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at ff00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at fe00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at fd00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at effff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-UD3R Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at efff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0000000-e01fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0200000-00000000e03fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: efd00000-efdfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0400000-00000000e05fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: efc00000-efcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000efe00000-00000000efefffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at fc00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at fb00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at fa00 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at efffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIB (ICH10) LPC Interface Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1 (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device b002
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at f900 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f800 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-DS5/GA-EG45M-DS2H Motherboard
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 6
    Memory at efffd000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 0500 [size=32]

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2 (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device b002
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f600 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f500 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f400 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f300 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f200 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f100 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 2069
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at ea000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at dc000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    I/O ports at ef00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at d8000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 2069
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at edffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB368 IDE controller (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device b000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at df00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at de00 [size=4]
    I/O ports at dd00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=4]
    I/O ports at db00 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pata_jmicron

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at ce00 [size=256]
    Memory at efeff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at efef8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at efe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:28:c7:0a:42:a2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7185 errors:0 dropped:14 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1453858 (1.4 MB)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:814074 (814.0 KB)  TX bytes:814074 (814.0 KB)
```

`lshw -c network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:28:c7:0a:42:a2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.036.00-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:efeff000-efefffff memory:efef8000-efefbfff memory:efe00000-efe1ffff

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIB (ICH10) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB368 IDE controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
```

im also willing to do a fresh install if someone can help me fix this problem...

an update:
freshly installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit Edition still no internt:
trying to install build essentials downloaded it from the internet onto a usb and i get
Dependency is not satisfiable: g++ (>=4:4.4.3) when i click on the file
build-essential_11.6ubuntu4_amd64.deb on the usb drive.

i also have both realtek drivers on the usb device both
r8168_8.035.00.orig.tar.bz2 which i got from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/r8168-dkms) & r8168_8.036.00.tar.bz2 which i got from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)

copied both to the home directory extracted 
opened terminal running command

```
cd /r8168-8.036.00 then ./autorun.sh
```

I will post logs soon:

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you rewrite your question to be more succinct about what the issue is exactly and what you've tried? Right now it's more with quite some personal frustration - which does not help in getting an answer, I'm afraid. Also please take care about proper formatting - it helps a lot to read your question and improves the chance of finding answers.

Comment: The issue is iv istalled ubuntu 13.04 and their is no internet connection ill reword it but i tried to provide as much information as possible this is my first time actually using a online forum for help so apologies if it wasnt clear and yes iv been extremely frustrated with this.

Comment: Try open up terminal and type
sudo dhclient eth0

Comment: that gives me a flashing cursor and the command does not go through it just hangs.

Comment: Going to install ubuntu and do this step by step and give u guys every step as i do it downloading [RealTekDrivers](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/r8168_8.035.00.orig.tar.bz2) Downloading Build essentials and putting that all on a flash drive going to install build essentials then try compiling the realtek drivers, then ill try running the command sudo dhclient eth0 will let you know results

Comment: Update attempted to manually input Ipaddrss dns etc. googled my problem and it seems its an on going problem since Ubuntu 11 now still carried onto to Ubuntu 13.04 hope this issue is fixed until then im going back to running debian mint really wanted to fix this i love the unity interface and ubuntu all around if someone has a fix for this network issue please let me know. thank you.

Comment: +1 Having the exact same problem, and tried the exact same steps. Wireless finds all networks available - can not connect to any. Wired can not connect either. None of the answers provided so far seem to fix this. Any further help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my realtek driver, did all the same stuff (using r8168)expect I starting with trying to run DHCP.  When i switched to static it went away (but making it static took some trickery because for whatever reason if i clicked add it wouldn't let me save the config).  I would suggest running in static and make sure you dont have an address saved in your router for that MAC address.  I am by all definitions a noob but it worked for me.

Good Luck,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Josh! Thanks for posting this answer, although, it would be great if you actually include steps on how to "switch it to static". Because your answer just says "switch to static", but not everyone knows how to do that =), and especially because you said "it took some trickery". We like to post informative and definitive answers here at Ask Ubuntu. You can always [edit] your answer to include more information by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the text of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer it is helpful +1. Maybe the static routing table on my router is causing my issue. I will try to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution I found was resetting the BIOS.

I installed Ubuntu. Then worked on it for a few days. Then installed Apache2 and Tomcat. Suddenly the wired internet stopped working. looking at the dmesg log, I could see that connecting to eth0 failed on the r8169 port.

Eventually I tried to reinstall Ubuntu (12.04). The installation program failed to find internet (something which was successful a few days earlier). Suspecting HW problem I updated BIOS to latest version (ASUS M4A785-M). It didnt help. Struggling a few more hours, then tried to **reset the BIOS (removing the battery and shortcutting the reset pin** on the motherboard). This did the trick. Now the wired NW works again.

BTW. When the Wired NW failed, wifi still worked flawless (via wifi dongle).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share this, not sure if this is the key to all problems but ...
I have a brand new Optiplex 3010 with Windows 7 installed and wanted Ubuntu as dual boot system. Could not get Ubuntu to recognize the network card, rebuilt the kernel per instructions here, installed and re-installed 13.10 Desktop several times. It shows no network connection during the install. 
One article I found in my many switches back and forth to Windows was that windows shuts off the network and the Ubuntu driver then cannot find it. Not a difference, or I have not found the switch the undoes that.

I just took a different network cable to a different port on the router and plugged it into the system, voilà there is the network. Now upgrading to 14.04 and responding to this. 
What I am saying is, that unless there is a network cabling issue (not sure why the windows driver should be less sensitive to this than the Ubuntu driver) there seems to be something switched off in the router or some established ip-address ignored when windows switches the network off to preserve power. A different port/ip is recognized.

This is for the real guru's to investigate.

Anyway, lets see what happens next. The driver that is loaded at this time is r8169.